# how to simplify smalltalk expression by using as less brackets as possible

Tags: smalltalk

im new to smalltalk.
I and in my online course I got the exercise task to simplify an expreesion:

`((7 + 5) + (31 * 8) - (51 * 2))`

I tried different things out but to be honest I dont understand the syntax and everything else in Smalltalk. I could also not find good youtube tutorials.
Can someone help me and explain me of to use as less brakets as possible?
and if there are good pages/videos to learn Smalltalk please let me know.

Comment: I don't know smalltalk personally, but in other langage you would do 7+5+31*8-51*2, and it would be enough (simple math priority, * is done before + and -, so brackets are a bit unnecessary, with only ), let me tell you if that help, if not, i'll check this out quickly on my lunch break. For example in Powershell, without brackets give the same result, it might just be a trap example in your course.

Comment: hello, thanks for your support. i think smalltalk will not work like this. in smalltalk everything is an object and message based...

Comment: Ok, just checked it out. Smalltalk indead doesn't work like that as number are object, and symbols are function, the best i got quickly is : 7 + 5 + ( 31 * 8 - ( 51 * 2 ) ), 7 calls + with 5 as argument, then the object in result call + with ( 31 * 8 - ( 51 * 2 ) ), and the same logic apply. You need to get at least a pair of brackets for each *

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**

```
7 + 5 + (31 * 8) - (51 * 2)
```

**Background:** Smalltalk has a *uniform* metaphor and syntax whose expressions are messages of the form `receiver selector argument(s)`. Here *uniform* means, well, uniform. For example the sum `7 + 5` is a message with receiver `7`, selector `+` and argument `5`. Similarly, in `31 * 8` the receiver is `31`, the selector `*` and the argument `8`.

The idea is that, in Smalltalk, messages are the only computation and therefore all actions are message sends. This might sound strange at first glance, but is actually a very smart simplification: messages are the only concept you have to master.

**Explanation:** Let's now consider the first part of your expression

```
(7 + 5) + (31 * 8)
```

Since messages are the main construct, we can get rid of the first pair of parentheses: once we parse `7 + 5`, we already have a complete unit of computation. Now, mentally replace this message with its answer: `12` and advance to the next message. You get: `12 + (31 * 8)`, right? This means that this time the argument of `+` is `31 * 8`.

Ok. So far we know that `(7 + 5) + (31 * 8)` is the same as `7 + 5 + (31 * 8)`, which agrees with our knowledge of mathematics. The question is, can we get rid of the parentheses around `31 * 81`? The answer is no, we can't. Let's see why. Once we replace `7 + 5` with `12`, after removing the parentheses we would get `12 + 31 * 8`. If we now parse this expression we will stop right after reading `31` and will interpret that the message just read is `12 + 31`. Then we would replace this with `43` and look for the next message: `43 * 8`. The actual intend, however, was to have `31 * 8` as the argument of `+` sent to `12`, i.e., `12 + (31 * 8)`.

In contrast, in the traditional notation, when we say `12 + 31 * 8`, we think of someone (or something) who would apply the precedence rules and sum `12` with `31 * 8`. Who incarnates such a role? The system? the computer? us? In Smalltalk that someone or something is always explicit: it is the receiver of the message. That's why you don't think of `7 + 5` as an instruction to someone to take care of the sum, you explicitly asks `7` to perform `+ 5` and provide the result. This is a subtle but important conceptual difference, not just a notational eccentricity.

The last part can be analyzed in a similar way.

---

**Addendum**

One of the comments mentions another answer, namely

```
7 + 5 + (31 * 8 - (51 * 2))
```

While this expression would give the same result, it is computationally different from

```
7 + 5 + (31 * 8) - (51 * 2)
```

Once again, understanding the difference is a good exercise, so let's do it!

Since the first part is the same in both expressions the issue reduces to compare

```
12 + (31 * 8) - (51 * 2)
```

with

```
12 + (31 * 8 - (51 * 2))
```

In the first expression the argument of `12 +`  is `31 * 8`. In the second `31 * 8 - (51 * 2)`. So, these messages aren't the same: they differ in the argument.

Of course, one may be tempted to say: *yes, but the result is the same*. Sure it is. But what we are trying to do here is to get rid of unnecessary parentheses, and not to find a shorter expression that would give the same result. Had this last one be the problem, the correct answer would have been `158`.

**Addendum 2**

A question remains (see the comment below). Is the syntactic difference between both expressions relevant? Yes, it is and here is why.

To better analyze the issue, let's simplify and abstract it by considering the difference between

```
a + (b - c)
```

and

```
a + b - c
```

The latter expression first performs `a + b` and then subtracts `c`. Now, imagine that these quantities are floats. Consider the case where `a = b` and `c` is greater enough than `b` so that `b - c` evaluates to `-c` but `2*b - c` doesn't (in other words, `c` doesn't notice `b` but does notice `2*b`). Then `a + (b - c)` would first evaluate to `a - c` and then to `-c` while `a + b - c` would evaluate to `2*b - c`, which is different.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this proper explanation, but I have a question, is there a point of giving a smaller argument to 12 ? (Speed maybe ? Easier to read ? Or down to personnal preference). There's not only the result that is the same, but (if i'm correct) the number of operation done remains the same, i'll just say that the only the order of instructions are different, am i getting this wrong ?

Comment: @Vollfeiw Thanks for the question. Please see my second Addendum.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Feels like pure experience talking, ever had this kind of situation where the order did really make a difference ? Is it really a problem too with integer, or just a float problem ? I hope i keep that in mind if I see a similar problem someday, hope i'll never have to use this tho :D

Comment: This is only with floats, and of course common to all programming languages. In Smalltalk integer arithmetic is never a problem. The reason I mentioned it here was for illustrating the way the syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the question as asked:

The number of parentheses can be reduced
by rearranging the terms to take advantage of
the order in which expressions are evaluated
when there are no parentheses.

Using the rules for Smalltalk,
(as described in the answer above)
we're allowed to simplify
an expression like this:

```
((7 + 5) + (d * c) - (b * a))
```

by rearranging the terms like this:

```
c * d - (a * b) + e + f
```